# Python Tkinter Frame Destroy to display new data

Tags: python, tkinter

App works fine when first loaded. I need to update data on each frame to display what the user has changed.
I know I need to somehow destroy the frame to reload the data. Any suggestions on how to edit switch_frame to destroy to previous frame?

```
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand="true")
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
 
        for F in (homepage, page2, page3):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.switch_frame("homepage")


    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        frame = self.frames[frame_class]
        frame.tkraise()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

`your_frame_name.destroy()` to destroy the frame

or

`your_label_or_something_other_like_button_name.config(text='you can change text or anyting other you want` to set new data

I hope this help you and feel free to ask again if you didnt understand something

Answer (score 0):

> I know I need to somehow destroy the frame to reload the data.

First, change the `__init__` to show only the starting page. Also, you can create a dictionary to map page names to page classes.

```
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.pages = {
            "homepage": homepage,
            "page2": page2,
            "page3": page3,
        }

        self.container = tk.Frame(self)
        self.container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand="true")

        self.switch_frame("homepage")
```

Next, modify `switch_frame` to destroy the old contents of `self.container` and then create a new instance of the requested page:

```
    def switch_frame(self, page_name):
        children = self.container.winfo_children()
        for child in children:
            child.destroy()

        frame_class = self.pages[page_name]
        frame = frame_class(self.container, controller=self)
        frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- destroy current shown frame (need an instance variable to hold it)
- create the frame when it is to be shown

```py
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # used instance variable so that it can be accessed in other class functions
        self.container = tk.Frame(self)
        self.container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand="true")
        self.container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.container.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        self.frame = None  # hold the current frame shown

        for F in (homepage, page2, page3):
            page_name = F.__name__
            self.frames[page_name] = F
        self.switch_frame("homepage")


    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        # destroy current frame shown if any
        if self.frame:
            self.frame.destroy()
        # create the required frame and show it
        self.frame = self.frames[frame_class](self.container, self)
        self.frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
```